# Fiducial markers - OpenCV - Feature Detection & Matching

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, sift, flann

Would somebody share their knowledge of OpenCV feature detection and extraction of fiducial markers?

I'm attempting to find a fiducial marker  (see image below) (self-created ARTag-style using MS Paint) in a scene.

[image]

Using Harris corner detection, I can adequately locate the corners of the marker image. Similarly, using Harris corner detection, I can find most of the corners of the marker in the scene. I then use SIFT to extract descriptors for the marker image and the scene image. Then I've tried both BF and FLANN for feature matching. However, both matching algorithms tend to match the wrong corners together.

Is there something that I can do to improve the accuracy? Or are there other detection methods that would be better appropriate for this application?

Portion of code:

```
GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector harris_detector(6, 0.15, 10, 3, true);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2; 

harris_detector.detect(im1, keypoints1);
harris_detector.detect(im2, keypoints2);

SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;

extractor.compute( im1, keypoints1, descriptors1 );
extractor.compute( im2, keypoints2, descriptors2 );

BFMatcher matcher;
//FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors1, descriptors2, matches );
```

Comment: Have you tried using SIFT (and not GFFT) to find the keypoints?

Comment: Yes I did. The issue with using SIFT was that it didn't actually locate any corners in the fiducial marker. So rather than locating a keypoint at a corner (high black to white contrast), it would locate points completely black or completely white.

Comment: SIFT is right in what it is doing. Keypoints needn't be necessarily corners. What results do you get on replacing GFFT by SIFT?

Comment: You are correct... I dismissed SIFT too quickly. I actually got SIFT to detect, and extract fairly well. Using FLANN for matching. It's still picking up a few outliers that shouldn't be matches. So I can detect and locate fiducials, but it isn't very robust right now over a set of images since a few outliers throw off the findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC) function.

Comment: That's one of the problems with something like Homography. Try adjusting different parameters you have according to the image you have. FLANN should have some parameter for distance as well, if I recall.

Comment: Got it working pretty well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use ORB detector， which is a fusion of FAST keypoint detector and BRIEF descriptor. it is fast and better than BRIEF descriptor because the later does not compute the orientation.

1. you can found a example of orb's usage in  samples/cpp/tutorial_code/features2D/AKAZE_tracking or [enter link description here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/features2D/AKAZE_tracking)
2. or there is a python project which does the similar task as yours [fiducial](https://github.com/mattvenn/fiducial)

Comment: Thanks! I will look through these